# python code: pgsql function execute throwing error when encounter special character in string

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Function `writeToDb` receive continuous log from sshd, http and ssl daemon, when any special char encounter in log it is throwing error.

```
def writeToDb(self):
    value_string = "'" + str(self.timestamp) + "'," + self.message + "'"
    query = "insert into syslog (timestamp, message)"
    query = query + "values (" + value_string + ")"
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Testdb' user='admin' host='localhost' password=''")
        conn.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute(query)



curs.execute(query)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "t"
LINE 1: ...','timestamp','File lastlog Couldn't locate...
                                                        ^
```

I can handle exception using below

```
except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
     pass
```

If query input by user I can give additional `'` single quote in string. I am new in python, anyone can suggest how to handle any special character coming from external log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't want to build queries just by adding strings together in any language. It is dangerous as that string can contain any valid SQL commands that will then be blindly executed by DB engine (consider `message="); DROP SCHEMA public;"`).

In most languages and DB libraries there are safe mechanisms to substitute arguments in queries. In psycopg2 you would do it like this:

```py
query = "insert into syslog (timestamp, message) values (%s, %s)"
curs.execute(query, (self.timestamp, self.message))
```

`%s` marks are positional placeholders. psycopg2 will replace them safely with variables in tuple passed to it as second argument (so first `%s` will become `self.timestamp`...). By safely I mean it will handle **escaping** (replacing characters that have special meaning in SQL). See here in-depth description of problem and how to solve it in psycopg2: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters

Comment: thanks for quick respond! Can i write like this `value_string = "'" + str(self.timestamp) + "'," + ("%s") + "'"` then `curs.execute(query, (self.message))`

Comment: @Kulamani No, that will not work because `%s` means string. It basically allows you to say "here will be a variable I provide to `curs.execute(query, (HERE))` and it should be considered **string**". Psycopg2 will quote it for you so you will then get an error that you are trying to insert two columns but are providing just one value. With `%s` you really want to pass just one column as I showed up in my example above.